# The Registry pattern: to use or not to use

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am considering using the Registry pattern in my application to store weak pointers to some of app's windows and panes. The general structure of the application is shown below.

[image: Application diagram]

The application has one MainFrame top level window with few child panes within it. There can be many of TabPane type based tabs. I need to reference the ParamsPane panel from all of my TabPane tabs, so I need a pointer to the ParamsPane object to be stored somewhere. There can be a plenty of options, but the most obvious ones are (1) to store the pointer within the Application singleton object or (2) to create a simple registry class. Something like:

```
class Registry {
public:
    static MainApp* application;
    static MainWindow* mainWindow;
};
```

Is this a good practice?  What are the benefits and caveats of such an approach?

Comment: I can't help you I'm afraid, but +1 for the nice picture.

Comment: Is your Registry class a complete example, or are there some missing members?

Comment: @Robert Yes, it is complete. But it will be extended with more pointers to the windows, panes and objects.

Comment: Ah, I see.  That is the part I thought was missing.

Comment: This Google Tech Talk covers the concept rather negatively. They refer to it as a 'service locator', and discuss it at around the 9 minute mark: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0

Answer (score 2):

It depends on why you want to reference `ParamsPane`. I can think of two reasons and two different solutions.

**You want to update data in `ParamsPane` because data in `TabPane` changed.**

If this data is completely separatable from the view, what you should probably do is separate it. This means following the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern. Both `ParamsPane` and `TabPane` instances can access the model separatly. So there is no direct reference between the two.

**There is some strong link between the two, irrelevant of data.**

If the previous mentioned point isn't relevant, and there is a really strong link between the two panels you could consider writing a specific `TabPane` class which stores a reference to a `ParamsPane` class.

I feel both these solutions are better than a Singleton or 'Registry' approach. Beware that I haven't heard of this pattern before, but I believe I understand its intent. More info on why global state objects (more specifically singletons) are a bad practice [can be found here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your response! Let me explain some of the application details. The ParamsPane is used to show the list of USB dongles attached to the PC. The TabPane is used to operate on the dongle selected. The TabPane should be notified of the events from the ParamsPane when the dongle is selected/opened/closed. The TabPane instance is created by the NoteBook object, so it is not given the pointer to the ParamsPane object. When the TabPane is created it needs a pointer to the ParamsPane object to be able to subscribe to the events the ParamsPane emits. That's what the registry is for!

Comment: @ezpresso: Looks like you need MVC to me. I believe, _"When the dongle is selected/opened/closed."_ would be your model.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of testability, it may not be a good idea to use the Registry Pattern.  To repost from [this article](http://www.brandonsavage.net/the-registry-pattern-reexamined/):

> Unit testing is predicated on the assumption that you are testing small, discrete units of code that do not have dependencies. This requires that developers do everything they can to either remove dependencies or mock them in such a way that the dependencies are neutralized as contributors to the failure of the unit being tested. In PHP 5, objects are not copied when assigned; instead, their address in a hash table is copied. This means that if you retrieve an object from the registry, and then modify it, every subsequent retrieval from the registry will reflect that modification.
>
> The reason this creates a significant issue is that it prevents you from testing a discrete unit of code. Now, instead of one thing being the variable in a test failure, there are two: the unit of code being tested and the object it retrieved from the registry. Any time there is more than one possibility for failure, the effectiveness of the unit testing is diminished.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this argument. The problem that the article excerpt describes (persistence of values in a registry) can simply be abstracted away with another mock object. This insures testability of the code that uses the registry. Then, you just need to test the registry itself to make sure it is persisting values properly. If some characteristic of PHP prevents this from happening, then it is a problem with the language, not with the registry pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Your Registry class and Singleton are OO-ways of global variables.  Prefer to make the Params Pane in the MainFrame and to pass it as reference to the tab-panes.